# TFS 2010: Multiselection in WorkItems is it possible and useable in the webfrontend?

Tags: tfs, web, workitem, multipleselection

is in TFS 2010 a multi selection control (listcontrol) available and if so is it useable in the web frontend ?

We have a customized form for test cases and would like to define multiple "verifier" for these test cases

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build two custom controls. One for the web and one for the windows. Then you have to modify the layout of the work item to have two seperate layouts, so you can specify that you want to use two different custom controls.

You can find some starter guidance at http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/10/Create-custom-work-item-control-for-TFS-Web-Access-2010-(TWA).aspx